# How do you solve differential equations that are splity up? e.g. y' has different values depending on if y is less or greater than 0.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example if   \begin{equation}
    y'=
    \begin{cases}
      h(x), & \text{if}\ y>0\\
      -h(x), & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

I tried to just solve them separately but then I ended up not having a solution for all values of x

Comment: Can you show what you have done?

Comment: If you include your work when you solved separately, someone might help. If you don't, how can anyone guess.

Comment: The split being based on the solution value is extremely unusual. Are you sure it is not based on the "time" value?

Comment: I just wanted to check that the correct approach is to solve them separately? And that I wasnt missing some other methid, if that's true I'm sure there is just a problem with my workings that I should be able to fix thanks!

Comment: No this generally doesn't make sense; if you think intuitively, what will typically happen is the solution will, say, drop to zero then immediately switch to increasing, then immediately switch to decreasing etc. So the problem makes no real sense.